# How would I test if a player goes below a certain height and kill them if they do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a map and I need to keep people from getting to my redstone.

I am going to make it so that it can detect them coming down towards it and send them back to spawn if they pass a certain height.

Comment: Is this intended to be played in singleplayer or multiplayer?

Comment: its for singleplayer

Comment: Don't even bother trying to come up with a command block solution, just encase your command blocks in bedrock.

Comment: Wait.. What does height have to do with protecting your Redstone contraption? (It's not like you're going to reserve the bottom few layers *just* for Redstone? Right?)

Comment: the place where the player is going to be is in the air because its supposed to be like he's in space and when he falls he he starts falling towards my redstone. the player can also get a jetpack which would allow him to actually make it to the bottom so i want it to just kill him ones he starts getting to far from wheres he is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MBradley said in his [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223108/how-would-i-test-if-a-player-goes-below-a-certain-height-and-kill-them-if-they-d?noredirect=1#comment301854_223108), **the simplest solution is to cover any redstone with bedrock**. If the area of redstone is large, you may wish to do this with the `/fill` command rather than by hand.

---

Otherwise, if your area of redstone is relatively small, you can teleport players inside a certain radius around the redstone. Place a command block in the center of your redstone (on a fill clock/repeat block) with the following command:

```
/tp @a[r=radius]  x y z
```

Replace `radius` with the radius of your redstone and `x y z` with the co-ordinates of spawn. Alternitavely use `~ -80 ~` to teleport them to the void and kill them.

The downside of this method is that the height of the command increases as the radius on the XZ axis increases. This means that with horizontally large areas of redstone, the height in which you are teleported may reach the surface. In this case, use the next method.

---

This next method does exactly what you asked - it teleports the player as they fall below a certain height.

*Credit to Skylinerw [here](http://www.planetminecraft.com/forums/how-test-for-player-height-t411410.html) for the command.*

Copy and paste this into a command block and put it on a fill clock/repeat command block:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @p[y=n,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] ~ ~ ~ tp @p x y z
```

Replace `y=n` with the y level which they should be teleported at (e.g. `y=64`). Replace `x y z` with the spawn co-ords or void co-ords as mentioned above.

<s>Please note that this method only works in singleplayer, in multiplayer it may not work correctly due to the `@p` in the `tp` part of the command.</s>

It does work in Multiplayer, as MrLemon stated in his [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223108/how-would-i-test-if-a-player-goes-below-a-certain-height-and-kill-them-if-they-d/223113?noredirect=1#comment301901_223113). My mistake.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong, for reasons I still don't quite understand which involve assumed default values for target selector arguments in some cases. Incidentally, prefacing the command with `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @p ~ ~ ~` seems to work, and you can then use the target selector arguments normally on `@p`, i.e. `@p[y=N]`. Also, the `@p` should be fine for multiplayer, since it executes at the position of the evildoer already.

Comment: What purpose do the executes serve? Why not just `/tp @a[y=_n,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] x y z`?